# Writing and reading the most recent(by date) rows from database

Tags: python

I have three questions on the below code ,basically I am trying to write rows with format currentdate ,count,keep appending the row date to teh same .csv file..read the recent most 5 entries and print it,currently I tried the below and running into following error.

1.How do I write a row  with format current date,count to a csv file
2.how to keep appending the same .csv file next time the script is run
3.how to get the recent(by date) 5 entries from .csv file

```
import csv
import datetime

icount=5
now = datetime.datetime.now()
time =now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#Keep appending date and count everytime this script is run
c = csv.writer(open("trend.csv", "wb"))
c.writerow(time,icount)

#Now read the recent 5 entries and print
cr = csv.reader(open("trend.csv","rb"))

for row in cr:    
    print row
```

Error:-

```
>>>>python database.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 9, in <module>
    c.writerow(time,icount)
TypeError: writerow() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Can you maybe add some detail about your output?  And why would you want to run the script to the same file?  Could you write to a new file and then concatenate all the files of a directory?  OR couldn't you just make a sqlite database?

Comment: @mcpeterson - basically I want to create a database every time a script is run..and based on the data I want to generate a trend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The error you're getting is because `writerow` takes an interable as an argument, so try:

   ```
   c.writerow([time, icount])
   ```
2. If you want to append to a file instead of overwriting an existing one, use `'a'` instead of `w` when you open it, ala:

   ```
   open('trend.csv', 'a')
   ```

   This is explained in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
3. You can probably do running a filter or sort on the rows from the reader. This may get messy so an alternative tool like [csvquerytool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvquerytool) could be helpful. There are few libs like this out on pypi.

Comment: can you throw more light how can no.3 be achieved?